# Using GameObject.Tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to see what gun we currently have equipped and play that specific gun sound, which I am doing by searching for the weapon's tag. However, I am getting the error 'Type PlayerWeapon does not contain a definition for tag and no extension method tag of type PlayerWeapon could be found'.

This is the section of playershoot script attached to the player prefab that handles the tags:

```
        weaponManager = GetComponent<WeaponManager>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        currentWeapon = weaponManager.GetCurrentWeapon();

        if (PauseMenu.IsOn)
            return;

        if (currentWeapon.fireRate <= 0f)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                Shoot();
                if(currentWeapon.tag = "Tec")
                {
                    CmdPlayTecShootSound();
                }
            }
```

And this is the relevant section from the weaponmanager script:

```
private PlayerWeapon currentWeapon;
    private WeaponGraphics currentGraphics;

    private Transform currentHolder;

    void Start ()
    {
        currentHolder = awpweaponHolder;
        EquipWeapon(primaryWeapon);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis("WeaponSwitch") >0f)
        {
            currentHolder = tecweaponHolder;
            EquipWeapon(secondaryWeapon);
            Debug.Log("switched weapon");
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("WeaponSwitch")<0f)
        {
            currentHolder = awpweaponHolder;
            EquipWeapon(primaryWeapon);
            Debug.Log("switched weapon back");
        }
    }

    public PlayerWeapon GetCurrentWeapon ()
    {
        return currentWeapon;
    }

    public WeaponGraphics GetCurrentGraphics()
    {
        return currentGraphics;
    }

    void EquipWeapon (PlayerWeapon _weapon)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in tecweaponHolder)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
        currentWeapon = _weapon;
```

UPDATE:

```
void Update ()
    {
        currentWeapon = weaponManager.GetCurrentWeapon();

        if (PauseMenu.IsOn)
            return;

        if (currentWeapon.fireRate <= 0f)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                Shoot();
                foreach (Transform child in tecweaponHolder)
                {
                    if(gameObject.tag == "Tec")
                    {
                        CmdPlayTecShootSound();
                        Debug.Log("tec sound played");
                    }
                }
                foreach (Transform child in awpweaponHolder)
                {
                    if(gameObject.tag == "Awp")
                    {
                        CmdPlayAwpShootSound();
                        Debug.Log("awp sound played");
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: How is the class `PlayerWeapon` defined?

Comment: Just a small comment on your code, you keep checking the same condition over in loops which aren't going to return a different result regardless of how many times you iterate through the loops... gameobject returns the gameobject which that script is attached to, and not the gameobject of the child that you are iterating.

Answer (score 3):

`currentWeapon` is a script instance that is attached to a GameObject. To get the tag, you must first covert it to a `GameObject` or `Transform` then you get the tag name.

Also, you compare with multiple `=` sign not just one. You assign with one `=` sign.

`if(currentWeapon.tag = "Tec")` *should be* `if (currentWeapon.gameObject.tag == "Tec")`

Finally, for performance reason, you should `compare` tags with the `CompareTag` function.

Use `currentWeapon.gameObject.tag` to get the name of the tag. For example, `Debug.Log("Tag: " + currentWeapon.gameObject.tag);`

Then use `if (currentWeapon.gameObject.CompareTag("Tec")){}` to compare tags.

Comment: I have tried another method, searching for the tag within the weapon holder game objects, which will be populated with a gun during runtime. The script now throws no errors but the gun sounds do not play still. The script is beneath the second snippet

Comment: This question is about `'Type PlayerWeapon does not contain a definition for tag and no extension method tag of type PlayerWeapon could be found` error and that's what I answered. You can ask new question for you other non related problems.

Comment: Well it is just a continuation of the same question, but okay sure

Comment: Not really. The title is about tag and the body is about tag error too. Sound not playing is whole different problem.

Comment: Okay fair enough but I cannot create a new post for another 90 minutes.

Comment: Ok. This comment section will be clustered with something not related. Put `Debug.Log("Your message")` in the if statement to see if the statement is even true. This is how to troubleshoot your code. Right now, you just said sound is not playing.Is the Debug.Log working?  You didn't even provide more info to help for your sound problem. If so, put CmdPlayTecShootSound() in your Start() function to see if that function is even playing sound at-all. Debug it one by one

Comment: The 'if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))' line is working as the Shoot(); function is being called correctly. However, the 'foreach (Transform child in tecweaponHolder)' line is not executing. And yes, the Cmd functions are working correctly as the sound plays when they are placed into the Start function.